# iOS FCM not working on downloaded app from AppStore Obj-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase-cloud-messaging

So i have this in my info.plist

```
FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled = NO
```

I am using .p8 (APNs Authentication Key) for my firebase project configuration. I don't generate and use the APNs Certificates (development or production certificate)

When i am testing using Xcode, both debug and release mode are working fine. all my devices can receive the FCM with no problem.

However, when I try to download the App from App Store and fire some FCMs, all the device did not receive the message.

this is how i set the APNs token

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
NSLog(@"APNs device token retrieved: %@", deviceToken);

[[FIRMessaging messaging] setAPNSToken:deviceToken type:FIRMessagingAPNSTokenTypeSandbox];
}
```

I have updated all my firebase pod to the newest one. And i am currently using FirebaseMessaging 2.0.7. FYI, i don't put in any App Store ID to my firebase configuration.

Am I missing something? Any help given is so highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm late, but you are configuring your FCM SDK for debug token by using

```
FIRMessagingAPNSTokenTypeSandbox
```

So the release build won't work.

Unless you have disabled swizzling you just doesn't need that line:

```
[[FIRMessaging messaging] setAPNSToken:deviceToken type:FIRMessagingAPNSTokenTypeSandbox];
```

Anyway if you have disabled swizzling (as you did)

> by setting `FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled` to `NO` in your app's
>   Info.plist

You need to specify the APN token:

> Swizzling disabled: mapping your APNs token and registration token If
>   you have disabled method swizzling, you'll need to explicitly map your
>   APNs token to the FCM registration token. Override the methods
>   didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken to retrieve the APNs
>   token, and then set FIRMessaging's APNSToken property:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
[[FIRMessaging messaging] setAPNSToken:deviceToken type:FIRMessagingAPNSTokenTypeSandbox];
#else
[[FIRMessaging messaging] setAPNSToken:deviceToken type:FIRMessagingAPNSTokenTypeProd];
#endif
```

Or just

```
[[FIRMessaging messaging] setAPNSToken:deviceToken type:FIRMessagingAPNSTokenTypeUknown];
```

or

```
[FIRMessaging messaging].APNSToken = deviceToken;
```

> The APNS token type for the app. If the token type is set to UNKNOWN
>   Firebase Messaging will implicitly try to figure out what the actual
>   token type is from the provisioning profile. Unless you really need to
>   specify the type, you should use the APNSToken property instead.